# selenium python selecting display hidden has image backbone js

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, backbone.js

I am new to selenium .I am having big trouble selecting id indirection and outdirection it clicks but changes are not affected .id directionsel opens recatgular image box out of which i want to select second and third arrow out of that image.Hovering on element also did not worked. Thanks in advance .
Below is html code for that

```
    <div id="directionSel" class="wosPanelDirection">
        <div id="popSiteLabel" style="height: 15px;">
            <span class="firstTxt">
                <label id="dirRefSite" title="NJ">NJ</label>
            </span>
            <span class="secondTxt">
                <label id="dirPop1Name" title="Ashburn">Ashburn</label>
            </span>
            <span class="thirdTxt">
                <label id="dirPop2Name" title="All">All</label>
            </span>
            <span class="forthTxt">
                <label id="dirOtherSite" title="All">All</label>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="dirSelected"><div id="biDirection" data-dir="0" class="bidirectionalTraffic dirClick">
            <span class="first lftPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="first lftPrivate">
                <img class="lftStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="lftLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
             <span class="third rtPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="third rtPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="fourth rtPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="forth rtPrivate">
                <img class="rtStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="rtLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
        </div></div>
        <div id="anap" style="height: 10px; height: 10px; position: relative; top: -10px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <span class="first">
                <img id="refAnap" height="13px" alt="" src="images/anap.png">
            </span>
            <span class="second"></span>
            <span class="third"></span>
            <span class="forth">
                <img id="otherAnap" height="13px" alt="" src="images/anap.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="directionValue" value="0">
    </div>
    <div id="directionPopupContainer">
    <fieldset id="directionPopup" class="wosPanelDirection selectionComponent" style="display: none;">
        <div id="biDirection" data-dir="0" class="bidirectionalTraffic dirClick">
            <span class="first lftPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="first lftPrivate">
                <img class="lftStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="lftLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
             <span class="third rtPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="third rtPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="fourth rtPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="forth rtPrivate">
                <img class="rtStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="rtLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="inDirection" data-dir="1" class="rightTraffic dirClick">
            <span class="first lftPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="first lftPrivate">
                <img class="lftStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="lftLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
             <span class="third rtPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="third rtPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="fourth rtPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="forth rtPrivate">
                <img class="rtStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="rtLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="outDirection" data-dir="2" class="leftTraffic dirClick">
            <span class="first lftPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="first lftPrivate">
                <img class="lftStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="lftLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
             <span class="third rtPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="third rtPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="fourth rtPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="forth rtPrivate">
                <img class="rtStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="rtLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="noDirection" data-dir="3" class="noDirection" style="display:none">
            <span class="first lftPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="first lftPrivate">
                <img class="lftStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="lftLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="second lftPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
             <span class="third rtPublic" style="display: none;">
            </span>
            <span class="third rtPrivate">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="fourth rtPublic" style="display: none;">
                <img alt="" src="images/green-bullet.png">
            </span>
            <span class="forth rtPrivate">
                <img class="rtStem" alt="" src="images/blue-bullet.png">
                <img class="rtLeaf" alt="" src="images/blue-light-bullet.png" style="display: none;">
            </s
```

I tried below code.Clicking event happens but not on that image box.

el=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="directionPopup"]')
                                                     hover=ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(el).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inDirection"]/span[4]/img'))
hover.click()
hover.perform()

Comment: I am using selenium webdriver with python

Comment: i got solution for that use jquery click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i found solution .After selecting element execute javascript click as "arguments[0].click()"